# How to export tables into files with field values as filenames instead of parts

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a very large table coming out of big query via Google Cloud Storage.

One of the fields in the table is ZipCode (00000).

is there anyway to query the table by zipcode, and export the results to files, with the zip code being the filename.  each file will have the records of that zip code.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution in python for which I didn't use BigQuery exports. The end result is nonetheless saved in Storage, as newline delimited json files (such that can be then loaded back to BigQuery). It involves a query which might get expensive for very large tables though. I used as an example a table with one ZipCode column and two more columns (col1, col2) but this shouldn't matter. Also, I hard-coded the authentication part.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from argparse import ArgumentParser
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import storage

def main(project_id, dataset_id, table_id, bucket_name):

    client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('service_account.json',project=project_id)
    dataset = client.dataset(dataset_id)
    # Create a table for intermediate results
    table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table('tmp')

    # Query job with 'tmp' as destination
    # Group by non grouped/aggregated field ZipCode using ARRAY_AGG
    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
    job_config.destination = table_ref
    sql = 'SELECT ZipCode, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(col1, col2)) FROM `{}.{}.{}` GROUP BY ZipCode'.format(project_id, dataset_id, table_id)
    query_job = client.query(
        sql,
        location='US',
        job_config=job_config)
    query_job.result()

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

    rows = client.list_rows(client.get_table(table_ref))
    for row in rows:
        record=''
        # Rest of row is a list of dictionaries with unicode items
        for r in row[1:][0]:
            r = {str(k):str(v) for k,v in r.items()}
            record+=(str(r))+'\n'
        # row[0] will have ZipCode which we want to use to name the exported files
        filename=row[0]+'.json'
        blob = bucket.blob(filename)
        print 'Exporting to gs://{}/{}'.format(bucket_name,filename)
        blob.upload_from_string(record)

    # Delete the tmp table
    client.delete_table(table_ref)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-p','--project', help="project where the ZipCode table resides", dest='project_id')
    parser.add_argument('-d','--dataset', help="dataset with the ZipCode table", dest='dataset_id')
    parser.add_argument('-t','--table', help="ZipCode table", dest='table_id')
    parser.add_argument('-b','--bucket', help="destination bucket", dest='bucket')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args.project_id,args.dataset_id,args.table_id,args.bucket)
```

Comment: so this basically uses python to send calls to bigquery using api to instruct big query to save as gcs file.  I like it.  THanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use some Java and Beam/Dataflow DynamicDestinations.

Your pipeline would:

- Read data from BigQuery.
- For each row, look at the specific column that would specify which destination file it should go to.

Take a look at:

- https://shinesolutions.com/2017/12/05/fun-with-serializable-functions-and-dynamic-destinations-in-cloud-dataflow/
- https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileBasedSink.DynamicDestinations.html

The question asked for Python - but currently DynamicDestinations are only available on Java.